# MySQL Query To Return One Record Per Group By With the Latest Status

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've looked at my query for a while and need a sanity check.

I'm looking to write a query that returns the lastest status, based on the group by columns. When I run this against my test data, I'm not getting what I expect. Each status is time stamped and kept for historical purposes. So when I do my query, I only want the latest one.

```
# All Records
SELECT * FROM msgstatus ORDER BY StatusDateTime Desc;

# My Query to Get Only the Latest Statuses (which isn't working as expected)
SELECT * FROM msgstatus GROUP BY Id1, ID2 ORDER BY StatusDateTime Desc;
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing or suggestion on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: you're selecting fields which aren't in the group by clause. mysql is free to select whatever values it wants for those fields, which are generally from the first record it encounters that matches the groupby, even if those values are from a record that wouldn't normally show up in results.

Comment: While this appears to fit the pattern of the most frequently asked question on SO, under the mysql tag if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @MarcB, You seem to be spot on. Looks like Group By has the higher precedence. Knowing this, it allowed me to come up with something that worked. Posted a solution, thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

MarcB's comment lead me down the right path.

In essence, it looks like the `group by` happens before the `order by`.

There may be a more elegant solution out there... but the following works for me and I figured I'd post what I have until someone shows something better :)

```
SELECT 
  Field1,
  Field2,
  Id1,
  Id2,
  ...
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM msgstatus ORDER BY StatusDateTime Desc LIMIT 1) as subquery
GROUP BY Id1, Id2
#ORDER BY StatusDateTime Desc # This is optional
;
```